# How to init again after ajax page change

Tags: javascript, ajax, gsap

I'm building my own web-site and I wanted in some cases to change page with an ajax call. The change itself is working, but to make the next page work properly I need to initialize the document again, and here's my issue.

I guess that I have to re-run my init function at certain point but everywhere I tried I had not the expected result

Here's my code:
*----JS + GreenSock Library----*
On document readystate complete I run my init function which has a case switch according to the page I'm going into.
This is my function for the ajax page change.

Here's the HTML part:

```
<body class="bodyHome">
    <div class="contenitore">

        <section class="contenuto">

            <header class="headerHome">
                <h2 class="logoInit">MN</h2>
                <h1 class="logoDesc">MyName<br> Web-Designer</h1>
            </header>
            <nav class="menu">
                    <ul class="menuul">
                        <li class="menuitm"><a class="menuopt link-ajax" href="index.html">home</a></li>
                        <li class="menuitm"><a class="menuopt link-ajax anchor" href="about.html">about</a></li>
                        <li class="menuitm"><a class="menuopt link-ajax" href="#">jobs</a></li>
                        <li class="menuitm"><a class="menuopt link-ajax" href="#">contacts</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </nav>
        </section>

    </div>

        <footer class="foothome">
*irrelevant code*
        </footer>

      
*links to GSAP and then to my js file*
    </body>
```

Here's the JS part

```
function ingrPage() {

    var linkAjax = document.getElementsByClassName("link-ajax");

    events();
    

    function events() {

        for (let i = 0; i < linkAjax.length; i++) {

            linkAjax[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                window.console.log("click link --->", linkAjax[i].getAttribute('href'));

                getPage(linkAjax[i].getAttribute('href'));
              
                return false;

            });

        }
    }

    function getPage(link = null) {
        if (link !== null) {
            fetch(link)
                .then(response => {
                    if (response.ok) {
                        return Promise.resolve(response);
                        
                        
                        
                        
                    } else {
                        return Promise.reject(new Error('Failed to load'));
                    }
                })
                .then(response => response.text()) // parse response as JSON
                .then(data => {
                    // success
                    history.pushState("", "", link);
                    var parser = new DOMParser();
                    var doc = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/html");
                    let newTarget = doc.getElementsByClassName('contenitore');
                    let oldTarget = document.getElementsByClassName('contenitore');
                    newTarget = newTarget[0];
                    oldTarget = oldTarget[0];
                    window.console.log('ok data ---> ', newTarget);
                    TweenLite.to(oldTarget.getElementsByClassName('contenuto')[0], 0.5, {
                         autoAlpha: 0
                     });
                    TweenLite.set(newTarget.getElementsByClassName('contenuto')[0], {
                        autoAlpha: 0
                    });
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        oldTarget.append(newTarget.getElementsByClassName('contenuto')[0]);
                        console.log("cambio eseguito");
                        TweenLite.to(oldTarget.getElementsByClassName('contenuto')[1], 0.5, {
                            autoAlpha: 1
                        });
                        
                        oldTarget.getElementsByClassName('contenuto')[0].remove(); 
                    }, 550)
                })
                
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(`Error: ${error.message}`);
                });
                

        }
    }}
```

How am I supposed to initialize again the document after the ajax page change to make it work properly? Thank you!

Comment: Hey moropulp. For debugging help like this you should include enough code to create a minimal and complete demo of your issue in the question itself. See [this help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more info. Otherwise your question is likely to be closed. Most likely you don't need to reinitialize everything, only the parts that are added in the AJAX change.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the tip! I'm adding the HTML part so it's possible to copy and paste the code to see how it works. By the way can you please tell me how to init again the parts you mean? thank you